# Converting DBF file to CSV using Python 3+ getting errors

Tags: python, csv, dbf

So I'm new to Python and my goal is to convert the different large dbf files into csv files. I have looked at different code and don't understand a lot of the parts. The below code runs for data1.dbf but not data2.dbf. I get an error stating:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte...

I did look into encoding for the dbfread but it says that encoding is not needed...The other part I need is to get these Large dbfs into csv. If I use the dbfread I'm not knowledgeable about the code to place it into the csv file.

```
import sys
import csv
from dbfread import DBF

file = "C:/Users/.../Documents/.../data2.dbf"
table = DBF(file)
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerow(table.field_names)
for record in table:
    writer.writerow(list(record.values()))
```

Here is another try using dbf library.

```
import dbf  # instead of dbfpy
for table in sys.argv[1:]:
    dbf.export(table, header = True)
```

This one is ran from the command prompted with the statement "*python dbf2csv_EF.py data1.dbf*" produces a different error when attempting both my dbf files. The error is:

> ...AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: Please paste the full traceback, not just a truncated part.

Comment: Can you include the full traceback for your attempt using `dbf`?  If that's a bug I'd like to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're on Windows and are attempting to write to `sys.stdout`, I think (part of) your first problem is that the Windows console is not very Unicode savvy, and you should write to files instead.

Assuming that's the case, something like

```
import sys
import csv
from dbfread import DBF

for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    csv_file = file + ".csv"
    table = DBF(file, encoding="UTF-8")
    with open(csv_file, "w") as outf:
        writer = csv.writer(outf)
        writer.writerow(table.field_names)
        for record in table:
            writer.writerow(list(record.values()))
```

might do the trick - running the script with e.g. "python thatscript.py foo.dbf" should have you end up with "foo.dbf.csv".

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  I end up getting an error on data2.dbf with this style for dbfread that is the same as above. >UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte...Do I need to do encoding on this? How would I do it?

Comment: Please paste the full traceback, not just the last line, in your original question.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dbf2csv.py", line 11, in <module>
    for record in table:
  File "C:\...\dbfread\dbf.py", line 309, in _iter_records
    items = [(field.name,
  File "C:\...\dbfread\dbf.py", line 310, in <listcomp>
    parse(field, read(field.length))) \
  File "C:\...\dbfread\field_parser.py", line 75, in parse
    return func(field, data)
  File "C:\...\dbfread\field_parser.py", line 83, in parseC
    return decode_text(data.rstrip(b'\0 '), self.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Then try passing an encoding parameter as per https://dbfread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#character-encodings (as I've updated the answer with).

Comment: The data comes into the CSV file with additional line break between each line. Do you know why?

Comment: Are you sure? What are you viewing the file with?